# Custom made stack's "seek" function returning the position in the array and not the value of the position in the array

Tags: c++, for-loop, stack

I have a for loop that is designed to take in a target number, and loop through the stack until It finds the data at stack[target] and it is supposed to return that data.

Unfortunately I can only get it to either return the position of the array that it's in or a string of random digits (which changes periodically as my code does).

I tried to just return stackArray[counter] but that acts as if i'm returning just counter.
I then changed the code to make a new variable and then return that variable and I'm back to the string of digits. I think it has something to do with the fact that my stack array is a pointer? Kind of hit a brick wall here so any input would help.

here is my loop(the lastest version at least. I've tried it a number of different ways):

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter < target; counter++ )
    {
        if (stackArray[counter] == target)
        {
            answer = stackArray[counter];

        }
        cout << "beep " << counter << " " << target << endl;

    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense either way. If you want the `target`-index item of `stackArray` you can access it directly (stackArray[target]). If you want to find the index of the array that contains the value `target` then your loop needs to run to the end of the array, not to `target`, and then `answer` would be set to `counter`, not `stackArray[counter]`.

Comment: Wow, suddenly it clicked that I don't need a for loop at all to access this.. I guess my mind is still thinking linked lists in some obscure way. I'm confused as to what my lab is actually supposed to do now.. it's like not even a lab if all i have to do is return (stackArray[target]) i think I was overcomplicating it because it just seems too easy now. thanks. edit again. I think what I'm supposed to do is the reverse since stacks are Last in first out, I think i get it now

Answer (score 2):

Returning the value matched in the `for` loop is simple. Just add a return statement inside of the `if` block.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < target; counter++ )
{
    if (stackArray[counter] == target)
    {
        answer = stackArray[counter];

        return answer; // <---
    }
}
```

This makes very little sense though as you already know what `answer` will be since you are searching for it with `target`. Your `for` loop seems incorrect as you are iterating up to `target` which means the answer is already known and can be accessed directly with `stackArray[target]`. In doing this search you want to search all the way to the end of the array.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, but that cout statement that i have at the end with counter and target is not what I am talking about, that was just a test to see what the loop is doing, what I'm trying to do is have the return statement return the value of answer when the if statement inside the for is true

Comment: Updated with `return answer;`

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this site, it says you updated something but that's confusing me. You quoted my code, but the only thing you changed is the cout statement. That cout statement is unnecessary. how i am trying to output it is by retuning it to the main program. all this function is supposed to do is return the answer, answer being the data at stack[target], so that cout staement isn't changing anything unfortunately, I don't get why it's not returning the data vs the value of counter

Comment: May need to reload the page again. Not sure why that edit didn't show up but a return was added and cout was removed.

Comment: I got my stacks lab done :) thank you for your help, I really had it **all wrong**. anyway. onto queues now. which is giving me memory errors of course

Comment: @user2271589 Well you're off to a good start. you'll get there